# TinyMCE only returning changed content after click, why?

Tags: tinymce-4

I want to extract content from TinyMCE seamlessly whenever a change is made. BUT it seems with TinyMCE 4.3 that the only way to keep getContent() returning the most recent changes, you need to trigger a click.

Please check out my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xxfm68ue/1/

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "exact",
    elements : "thisID",

    // Skin options
    skin : "o2k7",
    skin_variant : "silver",

    setup: function(editor) {
      editor.on('change', function(e) {
        alert(e.target.getContent());
        console.log(e.target.getContent());
      });
    }
});
```

Is there another way to extract the content automatically?

Answer (score 0):

`change` event triggers when *new* value is different than *old* value. So unless user has stopped typing (i.e. `blur` event is triggered), `change` event will not be triggered.

To track changes, while user is typing, you need to catch `keypress` events

The following code attaches event handler to **keyup** event. So now, **every single** key press (unwanted key press are checked by `isCharacterKeyPress()`) trigger the contentChanged event as well.

```
setup: function(editor) {

     // helper function for keyup event
    function isCharacterKeyPress(evt) {
        if (typeof evt.which == "undefined") {
            // This is IE, which only fires keypress events for printable keys
            return true;
        } else if (typeof evt.which == "number" && evt.which > 0) {
            // In other browsers except old versions of WebKit, evt.which is
            // only greater than zero if the keypress is a printable key.
            // We need to filter out backspace and ctrl/alt/meta key combinations
            return !evt.ctrlKey && !evt.metaKey && !evt.altKey && evt.which != 8;
        }
        return false;
    };

    //function which will act on "change" event
    var contentChanged = function(e) {

      if(e.type == "keyup" && ! isCharacterKeyPress(e) )
      {
        return;
      }
      alert(e.target.innerHTML);          
      console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
    };

//adding eventhandlers
    editor.on('keyup', contentChanged );
    editor.on('change', contentChanged );

}
```